# how to change values in a nested list depending on elements of two other different lists and function is difficult to read

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, tuples, nested-lists

objective of the function is to change the elements of this

```
image=[[(15,103,225), (0,3,19)],               
      [(22,200,1), (8,8,8)],               
      [(0,0,0), (5,123,19)]]
```

into this with encode(nested, message)

```
>>>encode(image,'hello)
[[(14, 103, 255), (0, 3, 18)], [(22, 200, 0), (9, 9, 8)], [(0, 1, 0), (5, 122, 19)]]
```

each character in the message is converted into it's corresponding ascii thing and then each ascii thing is changed into 8-digit, base-two numbers. got that covered.

now, to change the list like the above, what i have is:

```
def char_to_bits(char):
"""char_to_bits(char) -> string

Convert the input ASCII character to an 8 bit string of 1s and 0s.

>>> char_to_bits('A')
'01000001'
"""
result = ''
char_num = ord(char)
for index in range(8):
    result = get_bit(char_num, index) + result
return result


def get_bit(int, position):
"""get_bit(int, position) -> bit

Return the bit (as a character, '1' or '0') from a given position
in a given integer (interpreted in base 2).

The least significant bit is at position 0. The second-least significant
bit is at position 1, and so forth.

>>> for pos in range(8):
...     print(b.get_bit(167, pos))
... 
1
1
1
0
0
1
0
1
"""
if int & (1 << position):
    return '1'
else:
    return '0'

def message_to_bits(message): 
if len(message)==0:
    return ''                                                           
for m in message:
    return "".join("".join(str(bits.char_to_bits(m)))for m in message) 

def set_bit_on(int, position):
"""set_bit_on(int, position) -> int

Set the bit at a given position in a given integer to 1,
regardless of its previous value, and return the new integer
as the result.

The least significant bit is at position 0. The second-least significant
bit is at position 1, and so forth.

>>> set_bit_on(0, 0)
1
>>> set_bit_on(0, 1)
2
>>> set_bit_on(167, 3)
175
"""
    return int | (1 << position)

def set_bit_off(int, position):
"""set_bit_off(int, position) -> int

Set the bit at a given position in a given integer to 0,
regardless of its previous value, and return the new integer
as the result.

The least significant bit is at position 0. The second-least significant
bit is at position 1, and so forth.

>>> set_bit_off(0, 0)
0
>>> set_bit_off(1, 0)
0
>>> set_bit_off(167, 0)
166
>>> set_bit_off(175, 3)
167
"""
    return int & ~(1 << position)

def set_bit(int, bit, position):
"""set_bit(int, bit, position) -> int

Set the bit at a given position to the given bit (as a char, either
'1' or '0') regardless of its previous value, and return the new integer
as the result.

The least significant bit is at position 0. The second-least significant
bit is at position 1, and so forth.

>>> set_bit(0, '1', 0)
1
>>> set_bit(0, '1', 1)
2
>>> set_bit(0, '1', 2)
4
>>> set_bit(0, '1', 3)
8
>>> set_bit(175, '0', 3)
167
>>> set_bit(175, '1', 3)
175
"""

    if bit == '1':
        return set_bit_on(int, position)
    else:
        return set_bit_off(int, position)​

from collections import Iterable
def flatten(nested):      
    for item in nested:          
        if isinstance(item, Iterable) and not isinstance(item, basestring):             
            for x in flatten(item):                  
                yield x
        else:
            yield item
def encode(nested, message):
    position= 0
    fnested= list(flatten(nested))
    bitlist= list("".join("".join(str(bits.char_to_bits(m)))for m in message))
    for int in fnested:
        for bit in bitlist:
            return "".join("".join(("".join(str(bits.set_bit(int,bit,position)))for int in fnested)) for bit in bitlist)
```

the encode returns a string of length 1200 which is an epic failure and it looks very non-user-friendly.

please help

Comment: Can you explain more how the numbers change? I don't get it why `(14, 103, 255)` is kept but `(0, 3, 19)` is changed into `(0, 3, 18)`.

Comment: the function message_to_bits change the message ('hello') into binary. these binary stuff are the bits in functions set_bit, and encode. the binary of 'hello' is'0110100001100101011011000110110001101111'. position is always 0. int is the elements in image. so set_bit(15,'0',0) returns 14. set_bit(19,'0',0) returns 18. the int is converted into 8 digit binary and its last digit is changed into bit and the new 8 digit binary is changed into a base10   number and returned. the 1st element of the tuple has the bit of the 1st digit of the message's binary. 2nd in tuple, 2nd in binary, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First some notes

- If working with bits, use strings as a last resort
- Don't use `list` or `int` as variable names

And finally, this isn't really an encoding as you can't ever get the original data back.
Instead of doing this, a XOR cipher might better suit your needs.

```
def message_to_bits(msg):
    result = 0
    for c in msg:
        result = (result << 8) | ord(c)
    return result

def get_bit(num, position):
    return num & (1 << position)

def set_bit_on(num, position):
    return num | (1 << position)

def set_bit_off(num, position):
    return num & ~(1 << position)

def set_bit(num, value, position):
    if value:
        return num | (1 << position)
    else:
        return num & ~(1 << position)

def encode(nested_list_thing, key):
    key_bits = message_to_bits(key)
    key_length = 8 * len(key)
    print ('key: {:0%db}' % key_length).format(key_bits)

    # Mask keeps track of which bit in
    # key_bits we are using to set the value of
    mask = 1 << (key_length - 1)

    result = []
    for list_ in nested_list_thing:
        encoded_list = []

        for tuple_ in list_:
            encoded_tuple = []

            for num in tuple_:
                # Encode the number
                set_to_bit = key_bits & mask
                encoded_num = set_bit(num, set_to_bit, 0)
                encoded_tuple.append(encoded_num)
                # Move to next position in key_bits
                mask = mask >> 1
            encoded_list.append(tuple(encoded_tuple))
        result.append(encoded_list)
    return result

image = [[(15, 103, 225), (0, 3, 19)],
        [(22, 200, 1), (8, 8, 8)],
        [(0, 0, 0), (5, 123, 19)]]
key = 'hello'
print encode(image, key)
```

This outputs

```
> key: 0110100001100101011011000110110001101111
> [[(14, 103, 225), (0, 3, 18)], [(22, 200, 0), (9, 9, 8)], [(0, 1, 0), (5, 122, 19)]]
```

EDIT:
About decoding:
If I gave you the encoded list and the key, how can you tell what the bits were before the encoding process? You can't. The key only tells you what the bits were set to, not what they were before you set them.

That's why I recommended XOR ciphering, instead of setting the bits to a specific value, we flip some and leave others alone. If you don't have the key you don't know which bits were flipped and which were left. If you do have the key, you flip them again to get the original back.

Try changing these lines in `encode`

```
    ...
        for num in tuple_:
            xor_key = 1 if key_bits & mask else 0
            encoded_num = num ^ xor_key
            encoded_tuple.append(encoded_num)
            # Move to next position in key_bits
            mask = mask >> 1
    ...
```

then this at the bottom

```
image = [[(15, 103, 225), (0, 3, 19)],
        [(22, 200, 1), (8, 8, 8)],
        [(0, 0, 0), (5, 123, 19)]]

key = 'hello'

encoded_image = encode(image, key)
decoded_image = encode(encoded_image, key)

print encoded_image
print decoded_image
```

It should give you

```
> [[(15, 102, 224), (0, 2, 19)], [(22, 200, 1), (9, 9, 8)], [(0, 1, 0), (4, 123, 18)]] # <-- encoded
> [[(15, 103, 225), (0, 3, 19)], [(22, 200, 1), (8, 8, 8)], [(0, 0, 0), (5, 123, 19)]]  # <-- decoded
```

Comment: how do i make it print the new nested list only? without the key? and what do you mean cannot get the original data back? because, i need to make another function where i input the new tuple and it gives back the binary thing. and the only changable functions are the message_to_bits, flatten and encode because the task requires me to use the other ones as they are. sorry for asking too much.

Comment: You can take out the print statement in `encode` to get rid of printing the key. As for decoding, I'll update the post with information.

Comment: >>> encode(image,'hello')
[[(225,), (18,)], [(0,), (8,)], [(1,), (19,)]] i got this when i run the xor thing

Comment: Sorry, the indentation was messed up when I pasted it. I've fixed it now.